# How to use the same method name with different tags in an OpenAPI file?

Tags: openapi

I have a scenario where I have two different tags with same method name. But it's throwing a syntax error in Swagger Editor saying "duplicated mapping key".

What is the correct way to write this in OpenAPI?

```
   /get_property:
     post:
       tags:
         - Car
   /get_property:
     post:
       tags:
        - Bike
```

Answer (score 1):

`tags` can be a *list* of tags, not just a single tag. You should use a single operation and put all applicable tags in the `tags` list:

```yaml
paths:
  /get_property:
    post:
      tags:
        - Car
        - Bike
```